# Fourier transform and inverse calculations without residues and cauchy theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Do you have any ideas of a function other than the Gaussian distribution for which we can do the numerical calculations (by hand) of its Fourier transform and retrieve the original function from its Fourier transform without using Fourier transform formulas/properties, Residues theorem and Cauchy theorem ?

Comment: There are an uncountable number of such functions.  For example, any constant, $C$, times the Dirac Delta has a FT of a constant, and that constatn has a FT of $C$ times the Dirac Delta. What do you have in mind?  What are the restrictions on the function?

Comment: There are some discrete ones like the Poisson distribution and the binomial distribution. I believe the gamma distribution is also easy.

Comment: @MarkViola The restrictions are that we have to retrieve the original function from its Fourier transform with the Fourier inverse transform formula (for the Dirac delta, it seems that we had to use the properties of distribution instead of the Fourier inverse transform formula)

Comment: @paul The Fourier transform is a distribution on Schwartz space.  So the FT pair of the Dirac Delta and a constant appliesPlease be more specific.

Comment: @MarkViola I'm sorry but I'm only a beginner with the theory of distributions. I was thinking more about functions like the sign function, exp(-aItI) or the rect function

Comment: The sign function is not integrable and the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sgn}(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt$ fails to exist either as a Lebesgue integral or as an improper integral.  It's Fourier transform is the distribution $i2/\omega$.   The inverse transform of $i2/\omega$ exists as a principal value.

Comment: @Mason I tried with the Poisson and the binomial distribution. I just struggle to retrieve the function from its Fourier transform.

Comment: @Paul This answer performs an inverse FT on a $\mathrm{sinc}^2()$ function to recover the original triangle function:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71973/28112

Comment: Fourier transforms of power functions are also easy to compute ... like $1/|x|^a$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we reply to the comment "I was thinking more about functions like the sign function, $\exp(-aItI)$, or the rect function."

Let $f(t)=\text{sgn}(t)$.  Note that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{i\omega t}\,dt$ fails to exist as either a Lebesgue integral or an improper Riemann integral.

Inasmuch as $f$ is locally integrable, its Fourier transform exists as a tempered distribution.  To show this, we let $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$.  Then, we have for any $\delta>0$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{\text{sgn}\}, \phi \rangle&=\langle \text{sgn}, \mathscr{F}\{ \phi \}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sgn}(t)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-L}^L \text{sgn}(t)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)\int_{-L}^L \text{sgn}(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\,d\omega\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)\left(\frac{e^{i\omega L}+e^{-i\omega L}-2}{i\omega}\right)\,d\omega \\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\left(\int_{|\omega|\le \delta} \phi(\omega)\left(\frac{e^{i\omega L}+e^{-i\omega L}-2}{i\omega}\right)\,d\omega+\int_{|\omega|\ge \delta} \phi(\omega)\left(\frac{e^{i\omega L}+e^{-i\omega L}-2}{i\omega}\right)\,d\omega \right)\\\\
&=\int_{|\omega|\ge\delta}\frac{i2}{\omega}\phi(\omega)\,d\omega+O(\delta)
\end{align}$$

Letting $\delta\to 0$, yields the result

$$\langle \mathscr{F}\{\text{sgn}\}, \phi \rangle=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{|\omega|\ge\delta} \frac{i2}{\omega}\phi(\omega)\,d\omega$$

Therefore, in distribution we have $\mathscr{F}\{\text{sgn}\}(\omega)=\text{PV}\left(\frac{i2}{\omega}\right)$.

Now, if we wish to find the inverse Fourier transform of $F(\omega)=\text{PV}\left(\frac{i2}{\omega}\right)$, we proceed as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{F\}(t)&=\text{PV}\left(\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i2}{\omega}e^{-i\omega t}\,d\omega\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\,d\omega\\\\
&=\text{sgn}(t)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot

Comment: @Paul You're welcome.  My pleasure.